# how to convert var type holding URL attributes to string to use them for redirecting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

In the below statement i have tried to convert the var type variable "original" to string but it does not return any value to originalStr. I basiaclly need to concatenate this result with another string in order to redirect.

I have tried all the possible ways to fetch the value into string but failed. Can anyone please help to solve this.

```
var url = Request.Url;

var original= url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(url.PathAndQuery, string.Empty);

string originalStr= Convert.ToString(original);
```

Comment: It was a mistake while copying here.I have edited it. Please check.

Comment: what do you get in var original

Comment: Try `var original= url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(url.PathAndQuery, string.Empty).ToString();`

Comment: @coder771 this is what i get  in url and original 

url = http://localhost:12256/Email/Compose

original = http://localhost:12256

Comment: @BarryO'Kane tried that already. did not return anything :(

Comment: I tried something similar out here but I just created a Uri `var url = new Uri("localhost:12256/Email/Compose");` and it gave me a result. Step through it and see what the values of `url.AbsoluteUri` and `url.PathAndQuery` are when execution hits that line. Also, is `originalStr` null or "" after it's assigned to?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane I could already step through the value I got in var "url"  and see values for url.AbsoluteUri and url.PathAndQuery but finally i need to assign it to a string which does not happen.  while debugging I could find no value assigned to "originalStr" , it shows nothing. I tried using shift + f9 to check. it said "originalStr " doesnot exist.

Comment: i too tried with the existing code and it works for me. you can try in http://csharppad.com/ with var original= "localhost:12256";
string originalStr= Convert.ToString(original);
Console.WriteLine(originalStr); and it works

Comment: I know . it would work because you have assigned the value already in double quotes (var original= "localhost:12256") which will take it as string right? if we try using the assignment statements given by me above it will not work